# How to set source for opensearch-java client's PutTemplateRequest?

Tags: java, opensearch

With elasticsearch's RestHighLevelClient, we set source for PutIndexTemplateRequest like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.8/java-rest-high-put-template.html), or like following:

```
var request = new PutIndexTemplateRequest(templateName).source(templateString, XContentType.JSON)
```

However, with opensearch-java client, there is no `source` method in [PutTemplateRequest](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/blob/main/java-client/src/main/java/org/opensearch/client/opensearch/indices/PutTemplateRequest.java).

Is there a similar method that we can use to set source for the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this approach:

```
String template = "<your template here>";
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final var opensearchMapper = openSearchClient._transport().jsonpMapper();
final var mappingsParser = opensearchMapper.jsonProvider().createParser(new StringReader(mapper.writeValueAsString(template)));
final var templateRequest = PutIndexTemplateRequest._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(mappingsParser, opensearchMapper);
```